# can a sharepoint site have more than one DOMAIN e.i. DOMAIN\\UserName

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, event-receivers

1. I am very confused about the DOMAIN of username Which is actually
   the HostName(computer name). Is it will be same after hosting
   sharepoint site to some other remote server or it will get change.
2. And Please tell me if there is any general way to access the Domain
   Name programmetically(c#) becoz i have hardcoded the DOMAIN name at
   lot of places.
3. It is possible to have more than one domain name in the same sitecollection like DOMAIN#1/username and DOMAIN#2/username.
4. IF yes(for 3) then is it  possible to have same user in two diferent DOMAIN.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should be using a domain.

2) You can authenticate using machine accounts

3) You can have users from both the domain and the machine

4) You could support users from multiple domains via ADFS or Domain Trust relationships

5) In the case of DOMAIN1\user1 & DOMAIN2\user2 you have two users, theses are separate identities and resolve to different SPUser objects.

5) DON'T HARD CODE things!

6) If you need to get the domain a user belongs to you *can* do simple substring operations, just make sure you guard your checks.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, SharePoint doesn't authenticate multiple domain users in windows authentication mode. For example we have our Active Directly named mydomain.com and it has 70K active users. Our SharePoint User profiles are synced with this active directory. And only those domain users are allowed to SharePoint. If you have people in other domains then you have to bring them to mydomain.com to have access to the site.

If you are allowing Form Based Authentication(FBA) along with Windows authentication, those users can user their id without domain name. Then hard coding coding will be an issue.

If you are hosting SharePoint site in remote server like cloud It support claims authentication instead of windows authentication. Then also hard coding will be an issue.

Since we are sure that there is only one AD for about 70K employees, in our intranet we have hard coded the domain name in several places in code. If you are sure of the AD then go ahead with hard coding the domain name in code like "mydomain\username1"

Does it make sense? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I am very confused about the DOMAIN of username Which is actually the
>   HostName(computer name). Is it will be same after hosting sharepoint
>   site to some other remote server or it will get change.

If you are seeing the DOMAIN value as the same name as the computer name (and from what you are saying, it appears that you are), that means you are logging in to SharePoint using Local accounts.  That is to say, accounts local to that SharePoint server.

Usually the DOMAIN value corresponds to the Active Directory domain name, which is used to centrally authenticate users on multiple computers across a Windows network.

As far as the question of whether or not this value will change after moving the SharePoint site to some other server, I would say almost definitely yes, it will.  The only way it won't change is if the new server is named exactly the same as the server you are working on now, and all the users log in using local accounts.

If the server name is different, and all users log in using local accounts, then the new DOMAIN value will be the new server name.

Or, if users log in using AD accounts, then the DOMAIN value will be the Active Directory domain name.

Depending on how you are using it, or need to get the domain name, you might be able to get it from something like `SPWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName` [(or some other SPUser object's `LoginName` property)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.loginname%28v=office.14%29.aspx), which would give you "THECURRENTUSERSDOMAIN\username", and then you could just pull the domain name out from there.